# PHP CURL get cookie from remote webpage

Tags: php, caching, curl, cookies

Im trying to take the cookie file from the webpage with PHP and CURL: https://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/Aplicacoes/SSL/ATCTA/CPF/ConsultaSituacao/ConsultaPublica.asp

But after the first time i can´t take it more, the cookie is avaliable in the "RESPONSE HEADER" just in the 1º connection, after the 1º connection it isn´t more.

I tried to make a CURL request cleaning the cache, or avoiding the cache, but i haven´t success.

So when i try to do it in the browser, what i noticed is that all the time i clean the cache i can see the cookie in the "RESPONSE HEADER", how can i do it using PHP + CURL, i need to get the cookie?

Thanks!

1º request after to clean cache browser
[image: 1º request after to clean cache browser]

Next Access
[image: Next Access]

CODE:

```
define('COOKIELOCAL', realpath('./').'/');

        $ch = curl_init("https://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/Aplicacoes/SSL/ATCTA/CPF/ConsultaPublica.asp");

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);

        /* trying to clean the cache */
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "Pragma: no-cache",
            "Cache-control: no-cache"
        ));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        echo 'Cookie...........:' . file_get_contents($cookieFile); // Empty cookie file here until now
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

$ch=curl_init('https://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/Aplicacoes/SSL/ATCTA/CPF/ConsultaSituacao/ConsultaPublica.asp');
$cookiefile=tmpfile();
$cookiefilepath=stream_get_meta_data($cookiefile)['uri'];
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE=>$cookiefilepath,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR=>$cookiefilepath,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=>false
));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$cookies=file_get_contents($cookiefilepath);
var_dump($cookies);
```

Comment: It worked !! ... thanks a lot.  So the difference is the stream_get_meta_data() ?